# requests.Session().head() vs requests.head()

Tags: python, get, requests

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.head('url', allow_redirects=True).url # 1
requests.head('url', allow_redirects=True).url # 2
```

Чем отличается первый способ от второго? Какой из них лучше и почему?

Comment: Помимо ответа @mrEvgenX можно ещё посмотреть реализацию `requests.head`. Там под капотом тоже создаётся временная (на один запрос) сессия :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объект Session позволяет сохранять определенные параметры между разными запросами. Также если нужно использовать cookies и авторизацию, то будет полезно использовать сессию (получается прямо как в браузере, условно). К тому же множественные запросы к одному и тому же хосту будут использовать одно и то же TCP соединение, за счет чего будет прирост скорости.

Как можно заметить у объекта Session есть все те же самые методы, что и у основного requests.

Любые вопросы хорошо разрешаются в [документации](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/).